# Image upload fails with MultiValueDictKeyError in Django

Tags: python, django, file

I am calling the image upload API (Django REST API) from my view in a separate Django project.

**My View**

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
    try:
        resp = requests.post(
            "http://19.******/BankImage_API",
            files = {"file" :request.FILES['file']},
            headers={"content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                "Authorization": "Token 71117971*************"
                }, verify=False)
```

**API**

```
class Bankimageapi(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
            try:
                ........
```

When I tried to upload an image, I got an error in API where `FILES` is `<MultiValueDict: {}>`:

> `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file'`

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: once please check key name is 'file' or not  in request.FILES['file']... print (request.FILES) then you check it..

Comment: The name is file

Comment: `request.FILES['file']` in your view is a `UploadedFile` (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files)) and the `requests` library wants you to post the actual content of the file (in binary format). So you should probably `post` this: `request.FILES['file'].read()` or wrap in a `with file.open('rb') as f:`

Answer (score 1):

In your view, the received `request.FILES['file']` is an `UploadedFile` (see [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files)), which is a subclass of `File`.

The `requests` library wants you to post the binary contents of the file. You can access the contents of the file using (`file = request.FILES['file']`):

- `read()`: `files={"file": file.read()}`
- `file` attribute: `files = {"file": file.file}` although I'm not sure this will give you control over whether or not this is binary.

Furthermore, you should remove the `"content-type"` header, which is added automatically by the `requests` package. This seems to mess up the body of your request.

Comment: when i use this files={"file": file.read()} --> I got empty in FILES <MultiValueDict: {}>

Comment: Ok try the second option then, might need to open the file

Comment: Sorry Second Option Got error as :I got I/o Operation on closed

Comment: You should wrap the entire call to `requests.post` in the `with open...`

Comment: I got    `raise MultiPartParserError('Invalid boundary in multipart: %s' % boundary.decode())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'`   using `requests.post` in the `with open...`

Comment: error at api . The file passes from view to api . but the MultiValueDict is empty `FILES <MultiValueDict: {}>` in api request

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue. For some reason the payload of the POST request is in the body (check in your API view `request.body`) but not as POST and FILES data. Using `file.read()` and removing the `content-type` header did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `id` of the `input` in the html?

Update:

The `request.FILES` is a dict that references the objects by their id on the html.

Comment: I'm calling api In my view .. I get file to my view @Blackk.. how to pass the file to another api